# How can i do multiple buttons work at the same time? in React Native

Tags: react-native

I didn't understand any of the threads that already have about it. Can someone explain more easily to me how can I use onTouchStart and onTouchEnd inside a view? I want to use four buttons at the same time, it is for a game, when someone release the button should trigger an action, but the four buttons have to work at the same time, the first who releases should do the action.

Comment: Find a solution?